# How to subtract date with date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got current day by code below

```
var currentDate = new Date();
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
        var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
        if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
        var day = currentDate.getDate();
        if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
         currentDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

Now I have input type date.
So I want the date I add into the input subtract to currentDate 
what should I do?

Tks for your help!
Sorry if my english's too bad

Answer (score 0):

Just include momentjs, it makes rhings easier.

```js
var current = moment();

$('#datepicker').change(function(e){
  var d = moment.duration(current.diff(moment($(e.currentTarget).val())));
  var s = "days: " + d.days() + " hours: " + d.hours() + " minutes: " + d.minutes();
  $('#result').html(s);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js"></script>


<input type='date' id='datepicker' />

<div id='result'>
</div>
```